# writing in an html file through c++ program

Tags: c++, html, css

Hi I am writing a program which opens a directory, reads all the zip files and unzips them, then I want to create and html file and show all the pics in the unzipped folders in the new html file. I had read that using ofstream is a good idea,and I have been trying with that...but I cant get the pics to be displayed.

here is the code I have written so far

I would really like to know how to display the pics such that they work, especially this part --- myfile<<"  ";

thanks

// HTML part

```
  std::ifstream fin_html;
  std::string dir_html, filepath_html;
  int num;
  DIR *dp_html;
  struct dirent *dirp_html;
  dir_html = dir + "/" + "ExtractedZipFiles";
  dp_html = opendir( dir_html.c_str() );
    if (dp_html == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening " << dir_html << std::endl;
    }
    char test_html[2];
    std::ofstream myfile;
    std::string htmlFile= dir + "/" +"Images";
    myfile.open (htmlFile.c_str());
    myfile<<"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN \" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd \">";
    myfile<<"<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" >";
    myfile<<"<head>";
    std::string title="Sample Data";
    myfile<<"<title>"<<title<<"</title>";
    myfile<<"</head>";
    myfile<<"<body>";
    myfile<<"<br />";
    myfile<<"<HR />";
    myfile<<"beta data ";
    while ((dirp_html = readdir( dp_html )) != NULL)
    {  // printf(" inside the directory ");
        filepath = dir+"/" + dirp_html->d_name;
        filename =dirp_html->d_name;
        std::cout<<filename;
        myfile<<"<p>";
        myfile<<"<a href=filepath>"<<filename<<"</a>";
        myfile<<"</p>";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<filepath;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        test[0]=filename[0];
        test[1]='\0';
        std::string dir_htmlArray[12];
        //dp_html=opendir(dir_html.c_str());
        for (int i=0;i<=11;i++)
        {
            dir_htmlArray[i]= "ExtractedZipFiles"+filename+nameArray[i];
        }
        myfile<<"<a href=dir_htmlArray1> <img  src=dir_htmlArray1   width=24% border=0/> </a>";  //rtyin

    }


//  return 0;
    myfile<<"</body></html>";
    myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why the images are not being displayed

```
myfile<<"<a href=dir_htmlArray1> <img  src=dir_htmlArray1   width=24% border=0/> </a>";  //rtyin
```

If you look at the HTML you generate, you're probably seeing things like this

```
...
<a href=dir_htmlArray1> <img  src=dir_htmlArray1   width=24% border=0/> </a>
</body></html>
```

What you want to do is to replace those hardcoded strings with a valid path to the image file that you parsed. I don't know what your directory structure is like but valid HTML img sources look like

```
<img src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
```

Comment: so would it be like this myfile << "<a href="<<dir_htmlArray[1].c_str()<<">"<<"<img  src="<<dir_htmlArray[1].c_str()<<"width=24% border=0/> </a>";

Comment: OR myfile << "<a href="<<dir_htmlArray[1].c_str()<<">"<<"<"img  src "dir_htmlArray[1].c_str()"<<"width=24% border=0/> </a>";

Comment: Try it out and then check your output.

Comment: myfile << "<a href='"<<dir_htmlArray[x].c_str()<<"'>"<<"<img  src='"<<dir_htmlArray[x].c_str()<<"' width='24%' border='0'/> </a>\n"; ///This works perfectly